# Difficulty serving jupyter notebook from new domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyer notebook on an aws instance.  I can view it remotely using the instances public domain ( ec2-52.*aws.amazon.com:8888 ), and I can also access content served by an apache server using the domain I purchased ( http://purchased_domain ), but when I try purchased_domain:8888, I get nothing.

Im sure Im missing something basic.  How do I associate the jupyter notebook with the new domain?